# Why my regex replaces match pattern with function object rather than the replacement value?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I need a `regex` that takes the replacement pattern from a `dictionary`. I wrote the following code but the pattern gets replaced by the `function object` rather than the replacement value.

```
>>> import re
>>> d1 = {'a':'1'}
>>> d2 = {'w':'2','k':'2'}
>>> re.sub(r'(a)([wk])', '%s%s' %(lambda m:d1[m.group()[0]], lambda m:d2[m.group()[1]]), 'waka')
'w<function <lambda> at 0x7f1e281efc08><function <lambda> at 0x7f1e281efcf8>a'
```

Expected output is `'w12a'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becasue:

```
>>> import re
>>> '%s%s' %(lambda m:d1[m.group()[0]], lambda m:d2[m.group()[1]])
'<function <lambda> at 0x0000000002AB0128><function <lambda> at 0x0000000002AB0198>'
```

You're passing the above string as a replacement string.

Use replacement function as follow:

```
>>> import re
>>> d1 = {'a':'1'}
>>> d2 = {'w':'2','k':'2'}
>>> re.sub(r'(a)([wk])',
...        lambda m: d1[m.group(1)] + d2[m.group(2)],
...        'waka')
'w12a'
```

Comment: Is there any way the above regex can be obtained without `lambda`.

Comment: @BHATIRSHAD, With my knowledge, it's not possible unless it simple translation of `a` to `1`, `w` to 2, `k` to 2. For such simple case,  you don't need to use regular expression. Use [`string.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)